# Hibernate criteria Inner join to select

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have to translate the next expression into hibernate criteria api:

```
select * from games gs
INNER JOIN (select gg.ID, gg.CODE, max(gg.DATE) max_date from games gg 
where gg.player_id = 1 group by gg.ID, gg.CODE) ss
 on gs.CODE = ss.CODE
 and gs.ID = ss.ID
 and gs.DATE = ss.max_date
 and gs.player_id = 1
```

How can I do it? I'm able to create inner and outer criteria separetely, but have no idea how to join them:

```
    DetachedCriteria innerCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Games.class, "gg");
    innerCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("playerId", 1));
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("id"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("code"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.max("date"));
    innerCriteria.setProjection(projectionList);
```

...

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Games.class, "gs");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("playerId", 1));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.id());
    criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not support subqueries in the `from` clause. From the [Hibernate 4.3 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries):

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where
>   clauses.

There is a [pending feature request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3356) for this.

You'll have to rewrite the query to avoid that, or use native queries.