# Count(*) inside another count(*)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

First and foremost, sorry if this question has already been asked, but I couldn't find anything while searching for it.

I'm a newbie with Hibernate and I'm not sure if this can be done, but I'm trying to translate the following query from SQL to Hibernate:

```
Select count(*) from (
  Select count(*) 
  from table
  where field1 in (...)
  Group by field1, field2);
```

Now, I know I could get a List of the second query and check its size, but I want to do this with the uniqueResult() method, since it's more efficient.

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I was trying to do this with HQL.

Comment: Could be done with an easier query : select count(distinct concat(field1,field2)) from table where field1 in(...)

Comment: count return a number so count(count) is always 1, no?

Comment: @RC. no, he's counting grouping by field1,field2 .. so its essentialy like count (select distinct field1,field2) ..

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to do this in HQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35292542/4754790) subqueries in the `from` clause. You could workaround this by rewriting the query to counting distinct concatenation of `field1` and `field2` as already suggested by @sagi in comments, or, if you find concatenation costs too high, to something like:

```
select count(*) from table
where id in
  (select max(id) from table
   where field1 in (...)
   group by field1, field2);
```

Comment: Too bad you can't put subqueries in the from clause. I guess I can workaround that by getting the size of the list that's returned or by using Native SQL query.

Comment: Yes, it's one of the most wanted features in Hibernate. Hopefully it'll be implemented soon.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could just do:

```
Select count(distinct field1, field2) 
from table
where field1 in (...)
```

But I don't think that works in Hibernate.  One work-around is to concatenate the values (as Sagi mentions in the comments) with a sepator:

```
Select count(distinct field1 || ':' || field2) 
from table
where field1 in (...);
```

One note:  this version is going to treat `NULL` values differently from your original query.  That can easily be handled but it makes the logic slightly more complicated.

Comment: Both answers are the same as my comments :S